# How to set Selected field of TemplateField Calendar?

Tags: asp.net, calendar

How would you Set the selected date of a Calendar EditItemTemplate in a Gridview?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="beginDate" SortExpression="beginDate">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Calendar ID="cal1" runat="server" SelectedDate="1 june 2019"></asp:Calendar>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("beginDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

I Tried

- SelectedDate="1 june 2019"
- SelectedDate="2012/04/04"
- SelectedDate="<%# Bind("beginDate") %>" (This one breaks - Doesn't want to open the edit screen)
  <%# Bind("beginDate") %> Returns "2019/06/05" Which is a date field in a sQL database.

I don't know why SelectedDate doesn't want to work even if I hardcode the selected date as shown above.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedDate` is a `DateTime` property, so you could <strike>either</strike> set it in codebehind(i would prefer `RowDataBound` of the `GridView`) <strike>or on aspx via inline tags:</strike>

```
<asp:Calendar ID="cal1" SelectedDate="<%= new DateTime(2019,06,01) %>" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

**Edit** Since that seems not to work, use the codebehind approach:

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Calendar cal = (Calendar)e.Row.FindControl("cal1");
        cal.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2019, 06, 01);
    }
}
```

Comment: Error Creating Control - UpdatePanel1Cannot create an object of type 'System.DateTime' from its string representation '<%= new DateTime(2019,06,01) %>' for the 'SelectedDate' property.

Comment: All I had to do is Add the property VisibleDate='<%# Bind("beginDate") %>'